# Optimization challenge : combinatorics, graphs, shortest path?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Each **Problem** has one or many **Solution(s)**.

Each **Solution** has its **Weight**.

Each **Solution** leads to zero or many **Consequent Problems**, that must be solved if this solution is used.

There are **no cycles possible**.

Given the root problem, goal is to find **optimal combination of {Problem:Solution} pairs** that gives minimum (or maximum) Total Weight (sum of weights of all used solutions), so all consequent problems of all used solutions are resolved.

Is there any algorithm with the runtime less or equal to $O((P+S)^2)$ that calculates the goal? other words - without recursively enumerating all possible combinations (via cartesian product).

Comment: If the graph has cycles I would use linear programming, but then you will have to argue that you can calculate a non-fractional solution. With no cycles you can also use things like min-cost perfect matching where you are sure to get an integer solution.

Comment: @dtldarek  What graph are you referring to?

Comment: @avs You create a node for each problem and each solution, and then edges pointing from problems to their solution and edges pointing from solutions to their consequent problems.

Comment: I see.  Since you commented under the OP, and not under my answer, I wasn't sure.  Well, I revised the model.  I now create a node for each set of problems that is consequent from a single solution, and a node for the set of solutions that correspond to a set of problems.

Comment: @avs My first comment here was for the OP and it didn't relate to your answer.

Comment: @dltdarek, in your first comment here (for the OP) you refer to a graph.  So, we are back to my question: Which graph are you referring to?

Comment: @avs The OP in his question describes a directed bipartite graph where one side is weighted. This is the graph I'm talking about.

Comment: @PhilippMunin Could you state if there can be cyclic dependencies?

Comment: no, it is acyclic, however there might be dependencies like that:

P1=> P2=>P3
P1=>P3

Comment: was put on hold, unclear what I'm asking?? I'll try to update question and put more details. Moderators could you please clarify what is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

Define $w(s)$ to be the weight of a solution $s$, $P(s)$ to be the set of subsequent problems for solution $s$, and $S(p)$ the set of possible solutions for a problem $p$.

What we will do now is define the *overall* weight of a problem/solution, i.e., the amount of work that needs to be done to carry out that problem/solution taking the subsequent problems/solutions into account.

We'll say $W(s) = w(s)$ if $s$ has no subsequent problems and $W(s) = w(s)+ \sum_{p \in P(s)}W(p)$ otherwise where $W(p) = \min\{W(s) \mid s \in S(p)\}$. We look at the sum of the weights of the problems since all the subsequent problems for each solution need to be solved. Likewise, we look at the minimum of the solutions for a given problem since we want the cheapest solution. By starting at the trivial solutions (where $W(s) = w(s)$), you can eventually work your way up to the desired problem.

Comment: The OP did't specify if we can assume there are no cycles, in particular problems from $P(s)$ just have to be solved, rather than have to be solved _before_. In the general case you may have no trivial solutions.

Comment: @dtldarek Thanks for pointing that out, I misinterpreted the problem a bit.

Comment: Perhaps your interpretation is correct, we just don't know.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to implement it now. I'll post here the result.

Comment: Unfortunately runtime is also too big here - it's also doing recursive enumeration of all combinations. I updated my question with those details.

Comment: Is the runtime too slow even with dynamic programming? I.e., whenever you calculate the overall weight of a problem/solution, store the result in a lookup table and before calculating the overall weight of a problem/solution, first check to see if the value is stored in the lookup table.

Comment: Not sure how to measure runtime for dynamic programming algorithm. Is there any standard way to do it?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Well, we know for each problem, we have take the minimum of a certain number of solutions but the number of solutions is bounded by the total number of solutions so finding the minimum for one problem is $O(S)$, finding the minimum for all the problems is $O(PS)$. Similarly, summing over the problems for each solution is also a total of $O(PS)$. In addition, there are also going to be lookups in our lookup table but the number of lookups is bounded by the number of edges which is $O((P+S)^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

You said it: graphs.  Directed.  With labeled nodes.  The labels and edges are somewhat tricky, as follows.

Each node ''contains'' either a **set of problems** (a P-node) or a **set of solutions** (an S-node).

From each P-node, an edge goes to an S-node.  The S-node contains the solutions to the problems in the P-node.  The weight of the edge is the sum of the weights of all the problem-solution pairs.

For each solution $s$ in an S-node, an edge goes from that S-node to a P-node whose problem set consists of all the problems consequent from $s$.  The edge carries weight zero.

This graph turns out to be a tree.  Now find shortest paths from the root (a P-node whose set of problems consists of just the one root problem).

Comment: There is nothing in the OP saying the graph has to be a tree. Besides, shortest path won't solve this problem in a naive way, because, if my understanding is correct, you need to solve _each_ subsequent problem.

Comment: You wrote "this graph is a tree", I am confused. If you suggest to duplicate nodes when necessary, then you can get an exponential blow-up.

Comment: I didn't say I thought it *had* to be a tree.  But the OP didn't ban trees.  As for your second point, I agree and have revised the model accordingly.

Please see the revised answer.

Comment: With the new change, aren't you counting the weight of some problems more than once (e.g. if they appear in multiple sets on one path)?

Comment: @dtldarek, As far as I can tell, it is the sets of problems, and not individual problems, that must be kept unique.  If you see a particular example in which my current model fails, please share.  Thanks!

Comment: @dtldarek is right - this will not solve the problem, because ALL consequent problems must be solved, and shortest path will only solve one of them :-(

Example:
P0 -> S01 (w:3)
S01->P1, S01->P2,
P1->S11 (w:5)
P2->S21 (w:4)

Shortest path will be: P0->S01->P2->S21 => P1 is not solved => FAIL

Comment: @PhilippMunin If a solution $s$ (in an S-node) is used, then the corresponding edge leads to a P-node that contains *all* problems consequent from $s$.  They will all be solved, forming an edge from the P-node to an S-node that contains all the solutions.  Am I missing something?  Can you give a counterexample?

Comment: Ok, now I see your update, but it's not clear how you're going to build that graph. Can you plz give an example of some simple case, like the one I provided in my comment above?

Comment: I'll mostly omit the weights (I assume you know what they will be).  Here a solution to a problem "P..." will be denoted "S(P...)".  The set of problems or solutions corresponding to a single node will be surrounded with {}'s.

{P0} -> {S01} -> { P1, P2 } -> {S(P1), S(P2)}.  So far so good?  The weight of the last edge is the sum of the weights of the solutions S(P1), S(P2).

Now, from the S-node {S(P1), S(P2)} we have two outcoming edges: an edge to a P-node {all problems consequent from S(P1)} , and an edge to a P-node {all problems consequent from S(P2)}.  And so on.

Comment: Don't think it's a good way either, because you will have to create a cartesian product amount of nodes. Let's say you have a P0:S01. S01=>P1,P2,P3; P1:S11, S12; P2:S21,S22; P3: S31,S32.

In this case you will have the nodes will be like that: {P0}=>{S01}=>{P1,P2,P3}=>[Cortesian product of P1&P2&P3 solutions]

Comment: Perhaps Branch-and-Bound?